# Show only unique strings with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have results in a variable like this:

```
string(4) "iFit" string(5) "Žene" string(6) "Odeća" string(5) "Brend" string(7) "Trening" string(5) "Šorc" string(16) "Reebok Les Mills" string(9) "Les Mills" string(6) "Outlet" string(6) "Odeća" string(4) "iFit" string(5) "Žene" string(6) "Odeća" string(5) "Brend" string(6) "Reebok" string(7) "Trening" string(6) "Majica" string(6) "Outlet" string(4) "Yoga" string(6) "Odeća" string(6) "Odeća" string(4) "iFit" string(5) "Žene" string(6) "Odeća" string(5) "Brend" string(6) "Reebok" string(7) "Trening" string(6) "Majica" string(6) "Outlet" string(4) "Yoga" string(6) "Odeća" string(6) "Odeća" string(4) "iFit" string(5) "Žene" string(6) "Odeća" string(5) "Brend" string(6) "Reebok" string(7) "Trening" string(6) "Majica" string(6) "Outlet" string(4) "Yoga" string(6) "Odeća" string(6) "Odeća" string(4) "iFit" string(5) "Žene" string(6) "Odeća" string(5) "Brend" string(6) "Reebok" string(7) "Trening" string(6) "Majica" string(6) "Outlet" string(4) "Yoga" string(6) "Odeća" string(6) "Odeća" string(4) "iFit" string(5) "Žene" string(6) "Odeća"
```

How can I display only unique values? No matter what I do I get the sam result

What i did so far:

```
$arr = explode( " " , $string );
$arr = array_unique( $arr );
$string = implode(" " , $arr);
```

No matter what I do I always get the same result. But I need to put those unique values in the dropdown. Please help me find the solution.

This is my full code:

```
foreach ($collection as $product){
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();


        $categories = $categoryCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            var_dump($category->getName());
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get all categories in magento and put them down in frontend dropdown. Here is a foreach that I need to get all categories names but I get the result as shown above.

Comment: what's `$string`? is it `string(4) "iFit" string(5) "Žene" ...` or what?

Comment: Yes $string is the represent result. :)

Comment: For some reason I don't get unique array, so when I do explode, I get the same result. array_unique is returning all the same values again and again.

Comment: To little info to determine where it goes wrong. This works: $a = "a b a"; $b = explode(" ", $a); $c = array_unique($b); $d = implode(" ", $c); var_dump($d); Could you provide a working code example of what you want with comments?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that show the problem, with the expected result? Obviously this isn't returns the same value: https://3v4l.org/EvCvB

Comment: `$arr[] = $category->getName();` then `$arr = array_unique( $arr );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `array_unique()` is not working properly for whatever reason, try using this:

```
$string;
$arr = explode( " " , $string );    
$result = array(); 
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {    
   $result[$val] = true;
}
```

In most cases this is even faster than using `array_unique()`. Hope this helped.
You can learn more from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: No worries. Always glad to help. You should give the PHP documentation a read when you get the chance. It is better than my explanation and most times have alternatives written there itself!